# VS2012: Page inspector/"view in browser" won't work

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am new to website development, and I am having trouble viewing my webpage in a browser.

When I try to open the webpage in page inspector/ choose "view in browser" I get the following error.

Page Inspector:

**"The attached page is not running in a compatible Internet Explorer standards mode.
To use the latest document mode add the following meta tag to the html page: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" >`
To try to dynamically add the meta tag for this session click here."**

View in Browser:

**"Uh-oh, something went wrong! Error Code: 500"**

I've tried adding the meta tag to the source HTML and it still doesn't work.  Also, I am following step-by-step tutorials on youtube, doing everything exactly the same, yet it still won't work. If I open a ASP.Net webforms site I can view it in the browser, I'm just having trouble viewing them when I start from an empty website form.

Hope this makes sense and thank you.

Comment: please show us your markup

Comment: Here is the top of the HTML document.

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Registration.aspx.cs" Inherits="Registration" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server"><title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>

Let me know if that is what you need.  Sorry, not sure exactly what you meant by markup.  Thanks.